# How to set or change object's attribute name dynamically in javascript (especially in older javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This question has been asked and replied very many times but still I wonder if its possible out of browser to change dynamically an object's attribute name?

I have a bigger problem related to this but I have summarized the core to the one presented now.

```
var arr = []
var a = "newAttributeName";
var obj2 = {"msg": "hello"};
arr.push({a: obj2});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

In pushing obj2 to array (arr) I would need to change attribute name "a" dynamically (which is variable) to what is given as the value of this variable. But this does not take place. I only have [{"a":{"msg":"hello"}}] in the console. Are there any trick how to change attribute names dynamically especially in non-browser context?

===========================================================================
Ok, I present yet the wider issue of which the question was the part. Below is the working code where in the the attribute **dynamicName** should be updated according to the value of 3th parameter in the **buildNested** function. Maybe someone find the way to solve or circumvent the issue.

```
var parentObj =  
    [
        {"clientid": 0, "name": "Mike"}, 
        {"clientid": 1, "name": "Alan"}, 
        {"clientid": 3, "name": "Peter"},
        {"clientid": 4, "name": "Anna"}
    ];

var childObj =  
    [
        {"address": "address info 1", "clientid": 0}, 
        {"address": "address info 2", "clientid": 1}, 
        {"address": "address info 3", "clientid": 4},
        {"address": "address info 4", "clientid": 3},
        {"address": "address info 5", "clientid": 3}
    ];


console.log(JSON.stringify(buildNested(parentObj, childObj, "givenName", "clientid")));


function buildNested(parentObj, childObj, dynamicName, matchId) {

    var nested = parentObj.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        acc.push(
            Object.assign({}, item,
                {
                    dynamicName_: buildObject(childObj, item, matchId)
                }
            )
        );
        return acc;
    }, []);

    // **** here is the circumvent-solution ****
    nested = JSON.stringify(nested);
    return nested.replace(new RegExp( dynamicName_, 'g' ), dynamicName);
    // ***************************************
}

function buildObject(childObj, parent, matchId) {
    var filtered = childObj.filter(function(x) {
        if (x[matchId] === parent[matchId]) {
            return x;
        }
    })  
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: You cannot *change* a property name once an object property is created. You can create a new object and dynamically determine one or more property names, and you can delete unwanted properties and add new ones.

Comment: I have updated demo code - there were few bugs

Answer (score 2):

Use square brackets for dynamic property notation (aka computed property name):

```
arr.push({ [a]: obj2 });
```

Comment: Yes, that works in browser environment and with modern javascript. How about ecmascript 3 compatible solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure it's impossible pre-ES2015, because looking at the MDN documentation for object literals, the computed property name was a new addition in ES2015.

Comment: I added a roundabout solution by using regex to replace attribute names dynamically after reduce-function have come to the end. Not certainly the nice and elegant solution but I cannot find any other way. Still open if anyone has better ideas (and note: the solution must support ECMAScript 3. Otherwise Jack's perfect solution would be enough).